# Why is my button not working in android kotlin *There is no error*

Tags: android, xml, firebase, kotlin

The button simply doesn't work in the app i tried useing the synthitec plugin, databinding, and even findviewbyId() but it simply doesn't work this is the Fragment class->

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import com.enternal.weapp.databinding.FragmentAddPostBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_add_post.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.NonDisposableHandle.parent


class AddPostFragment : Fragment()  {
   private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater,
       container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View {
       val vieww:View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_post, container, false)
       val buttonpost = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.post_button)

       val binding = FragmentAddPostBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       buttonpost?.setOnClickListener{

           Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           val title = binding.editTitle.text.toString()
           val description = binding.editDescription.text.toString()
           addPost(title, description)
       }
       return vieww
   }


   private fun addPost(title: String, description: String) {
       val post = Post(title, description)
       val userId= auth.currentUser?.uid
       val ref= Firebase.database.getReference("/posts/$userId")
       ref.setValue(post)
   }





}
class Post(val title:String, val description:String)
```

And this is The layout file ->

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddPostFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="Title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:text="Description"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edit_title"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edit_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/post_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="post"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edit_description"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edit_description"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_description"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.211" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

i even redid the whole app but it still doesn't work
*THERE IS NO ERRORS IN THE LOGCAT AND THE APP DOSENT CRASH I TRIED EVERYTHING
PLEASE HELP!!!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `findViewById()` on the nullable `view` property of the fragment. There is no `view` yet because you're still in the middle of creating the View in the `onCreateView` function. You should call `findViewById` on the view you inflated, `vieww`.

However, you should be doing this in `onViewCreated()` instead of `onCreateView()`, which is the intended way to use the lifecycle stages. You can pass the layout ID in the super-constructor call to make this more concise.

Here are two different solutions:

```
// Without view binding:
class AddPostFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_add_post)  {

   override fun onViewCreated(
       view: View,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ) {
       val buttonpost = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.post_button)
       buttonpost.setOnClickListener{
           Toast.makeText(it.context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           val title = binding.editTitle.text.toString()
           val description = binding.editDescription.text.toString()
           addPost(title, description)
       }
   }

   private fun addPost(title: String, description: String) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

```
// With view binding:
class AddPostFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_add_post)  {

   override fun onViewCreated(
       view: View,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ) {
       val binding = FragmentAddPostBinding.bind(view)

       binding.buttonpost.setOnClickListener{
           Toast.makeText(it.context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           val title = binding.editTitle.text.toString()
           val description = binding.editDescription.text.toString()
           addPost(title, description)
       }
   }

   private fun addPost(title: String, description: String) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

My recommendation is, if you expect a function to always be called, like `setOnClickListener`, you should not put a null-safe `?.` call in front of it. Instead, rethink your strategy. If you are calling it on something nullable, but you expect it to always to work, that should be a sign that you are following the wrong approach. In this case, it would have indicated that you are calling it on the wrong property and/or at the wrong stage of the lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks the first solution worked but not the second solution Edit: Never mind i just forget to make binding end with  .bind(view) instead of with what i had Thanks

Comment: There might be a typo. Just going off memory.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in kotlin but shouldn't you find the button view as below...

```
val buttonpost = vieww.findViewById<Button>(R.id.post_button)
```

Note the difference between `view?` and `vieww`.

Comment: Thanks bro i really don't know what to say, i've been on this for 3 days now, i even started doubting the meaning of life lol but really thanks bro!!!!